# JSON to SQL Server 2016 missing rows from array

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, open-json

I am new to getting JSON into SQL Server 2016, I thought I had it down, but I notice that I am missing some details from the array, looking at the image, there are four address', but I saw there are some more address' missing for example Burrows Rd, and Urana RD. How can I make sure that all the address' captured?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/erzBV.jpg

```
@json nvarchar(max)

@json = N'{
             "response": [
               {
                 "application": {
                   "info": {
                     "dat_id": "010.2018.00036494.001",
                     "development_type": "Residential - Single new dwelling",
                     "application_type": "DA",
                     "last_modified_date": "2018-12-03T11:35:24+11:00",
                     "description": "Residence, Garage & Colorbond Shed, Demolition of Existing Residence & Tree Removal",
                     "authority": {
                       "ref": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0",
                       "name": "AlburyCity"
                     },
                     "lodgement_date": "2018-10-26T00:00:00+11:00",
                     "determination_date": null,
                     "determination_type": "Pending",
                     "status": "In Progress",
                     "notification_start_date": null,
                     "notification_end_date": null,
                     "officer": "David Flood",
                     "estimated_cost": "Not applicable.",
                     "related_apps": [ ]
                   },
                   "reference": {
                     "more_info_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/Application/ApplicationDetails/010.2018.00036494.001/",
                     "comments_url": null
                   },
                   "locations": [
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "11",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 1031272"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "680 Centaur RD",
                         "suburb": "HAMILTON VALLEY",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2641"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     },
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "11",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 1031272"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "Urana RD",
                         "suburb": "HAMILTON VALLEY",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2641"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     },
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "11",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 1031272"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "Burrows RD",
                         "suburb": "HAMILTON VALLEY",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2641"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     }
                   ],
                   "events": [
                     {
                       "id": "3680347",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-01T15:58:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Public Notification",
                       "event_type": "PNOT",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3680348",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-01T15:58:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Referral Engineering",
                       "event_type": "ENG",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3680349",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-01T15:59:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Referal Parks & Recreation",
                       "event_type": "TREE",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3680350",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-01T16:00:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Acknowledgement to Applicant",
                       "event_type": "ACKN",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3683617",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-21T14:59:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Site Assessment Inspection",
                       "event_type": "SITE",
                       "status": "PASS"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3685155",
                       "timestamp": "2018-12-03T11:37:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Assessment Report",
                       "event_type": "ASS3",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     }
                   ],
                   "documents": [
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/163129",
                       "title": "Statement of Environmental Effects - SEE",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=6hF7YEiv0qE=&fileName=Statement+of+Environmental+Effects+-+SEE.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/163139",
                       "title": "Site Plan and Elevations",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=1Gv3GVOIHCM=&fileName=Site+Plan+and+Elevations.PDF"
                     }
                   ],
                   "people": [
                     {
                       "name": "Karyn Ford",
                       "role": "Applicant",
                       "contact": "6023 8287"
                     }
                   ],
                   "extended": {
                     "software_vendor": "Civica",
                     "software_vendor_url": "http://www.civica.com.au"
                   }
                 }
               },
               {
                 "application": {
                   "info": {
                     "dat_id": "017.2018.00036017.001",
                     "development_type": "Subdivision Only",
                     "application_type": "SCC",
                     "last_modified_date": "2018-12-03T10:19:25+11:00",
                     "description": "Roads, Sewer, Water & Drainage for Two (2) Lot Torrens Title Subdivisi on",
                     "authority": {
                       "ref": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0",
                       "name": "AlburyCity"
                     },
                     "lodgement_date": "2018-11-14T00:00:00+11:00",
                     "determination_date": "2018-11-29T00:00:00+11:00",
                     "determination_type": "Approved under delegation",
                     "status": "Determined",
                     "notification_start_date": null,
                     "notification_end_date": null,
                     "officer": "Sharna Holland",
                     "estimated_cost": "Not applicable.",
                     "related_apps": [ "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/010.2018.00036017.001.json" ]
                   },
                   "reference": {
                     "more_info_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/Application/ApplicationDetails/017.2018.00036017.001/",
                     "comments_url": null
                   },
                   "locations": [
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "A",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 161410"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "419 Hovell ST",
                         "suburb": "SOUTH ALBURY",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2640"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     },
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "A",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 161410"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "Charles ST",
                         "suburb": "SOUTH ALBURY",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2640"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     }
                   ],
                   "events": [
                     {
                       "id": "3683888",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-23T14:03:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Acknowledgement to Applicant",
                       "event_type": "ACKN",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3683902",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-23T15:21:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Referral Engineering",
                       "event_type": "ENG",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3683903",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-23T15:21:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Referral Building Surveyor 3",
                       "event_type": "BS3",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3683904",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-23T15:21:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Referral Trainee Town Planner",
                       "event_type": "TTP1",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3684791",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-29T14:36:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Collected Determination",
                       "event_type": "COLL",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     }
                   ],
                   "documents": [
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/177392",
                       "title": "Subdivision Works Certificate",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=8qU1Pkawfvg=&fileName=Subdivision+Works+Certificate.PDF"
                     }
                   ],
                   "people": [
                     {
                       "name": "Eslers Land Consulting",
                       "role": "Applicant",
                       "contact": "6021 1322"
                     }
                   ],
                   "extended": {
                     "software_vendor": "Civica",
                     "software_vendor_url": "http://www.civica.com.au"
                   }
                 }
               },
               {
                 "application": {
                   "info": {
                     "dat_id": "010.2016.00034838.001",
                     "development_type": "Residential - New multi unit",
                     "application_type": "DA",
                     "last_modified_date": "2018-12-03T09:36:09+11:00",
                     "description": "Twenty (20) Detached Self Contained Residences - Kensington Gardens Retirement Village",
                     "authority": {
                       "ref": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0",
                       "name": "AlburyCity"
                     },
                     "lodgement_date": "2016-08-17T00:00:00+10:00",
                     "determination_date": "2016-10-24T00:00:00+11:00",
                     "determination_type": "Approved under delegation",
                     "status": "Determined",
                     "notification_start_date": null,
                     "notification_end_date": null,
                     "officer": "Christopher Eldred",
                     "estimated_cost": "Not applicable.",
                     "related_apps": [ "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.001.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.002.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.003.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.004.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.005.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.006.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.007.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.008.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.009.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.010.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.011.json", "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2016.00034838.012.json" ]
                   },
                   "reference": {
                     "more_info_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/Application/ApplicationDetails/010.2016.00034838.001/",
                     "comments_url": null
                   },
                   "locations": [
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "2",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 874732"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "100 Table Top RD",
                         "suburb": "THURGOONA",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2640"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     }
                   ],
                   "events": [
                     {
                       "id": "3583145",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-17T14:13:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Further Information Requested",
                       "event_type": "INFO",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3573096",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-18T15:34:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Public Notification",
                       "event_type": "PNOT",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3573097",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-18T15:37:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Referral Building Surveyor 2",
                       "event_type": "BS2",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3573098",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-18T15:37:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Referral Plumbing Inspector",
                       "event_type": "PI",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3573099",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-18T15:37:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Referral Engineering",
                       "event_type": "ENG",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3573100",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-18T15:38:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Referral Environmental Planner",
                       "event_type": "ENV",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3573103",
                       "timestamp": "2016-08-18T15:43:43+10:00",
                       "description": "Acknowledgement to Applicant",
                       "event_type": "ACKN",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3575194",
                       "timestamp": "2016-09-06T00:00:00+10:00",
                       "description": "Assessment Report",
                       "event_type": "ASS3",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     }
                   ],
                   "documents": [
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC16/209893",
                       "title": "Statement of Environmental Effects - SEE",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=sQkVV9rEsTU=&fileName=Statement+of+Environmental+Effects+-+SEE.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC16/209896",
                       "title": "Site Plan & Elevations",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=3dRqEZHzGeo=&fileName=Site+Plan+%26+Elevations.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC16/211819",
                       "title": "Assessment Report",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=DVTQkQQqbns=&fileName=Assessment+Report.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC16/240764",
                       "title": "Development Consent",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=TY+Y3zjyDKw=&fileName=Development+Consent.PDF"
                     }
                   ],
                   "people": [
                     {
                       "name": "Kensington Gardens Lifestyle Estates",
                       "role": "Applicant",
                       "contact": "6049 3100"
                     }
                   ],
                   "extended": {
                     "software_vendor": "Civica",
                     "software_vendor_url": "http://www.civica.com.au"
                   }
                 }
               },
               {
                 "application": {
                   "info": {
                     "dat_id": "010.2018.00036468.001",
                     "development_type": "Residential - Single new dwelling",
                     "application_type": "DA",
                     "last_modified_date": "2018-11-30T17:17:25+11:00",
                     "description": "Residence, Garage and Retaining Walls",
                     "authority": {
                       "ref": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0",
                       "name": "AlburyCity"
                     },
                     "lodgement_date": "2018-10-19T00:00:00+11:00",
                     "determination_date": "2018-11-26T00:00:00+11:00",
                     "determination_type": "Approved under delegation",
                     "status": "Determined",
                     "notification_start_date": null,
                     "notification_end_date": null,
                     "officer": "David Flood",
                     "estimated_cost": "Not applicable.",
                     "related_apps": [ "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/011.2018.00036468.001.json" ]
                   },
                   "reference": {
                     "more_info_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/Application/ApplicationDetails/010.2018.00036468.001/",
                     "comments_url": null
                   },
                   "locations": [
                     {
                       "land_title_ref": {
                         "torrens": {
                           "lot": "218",
                           "section": null,
                           "dpsp_id": "DP 1228226"
                         }
                       },
                       "address": {
                         "street": "20 Stockman CRCT",
                         "suburb": "THURGOONA",
                         "state": "NSW",
                         "postcode": "2640"
                       },
                       "geometry": null
                     }
                   ],
                   "events": [
                     {
                       "id": "3678966",
                       "timestamp": "2018-10-25T10:47:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Public Notification",
                       "event_type": "PNOT",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3678967",
                       "timestamp": "2018-10-25T10:48:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Referral Engineering",
                       "event_type": "ENG",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3678974",
                       "timestamp": "2018-10-25T10:51:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Acknowledgement to Applicant",
                       "event_type": "ACKN",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3681955",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-01T15:49:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Site Assessment Inspection",
                       "event_type": "SITE",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     },
                     {
                       "id": "3684251",
                       "timestamp": "2018-11-27T10:24:00+11:00",
                       "description": "Collected Determination",
                       "event_type": "COLL",
                       "status": "COMP"
                     }
                   ],
                   "documents": [
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/159026",
                       "title": "Statement of Environmental Effects - SEE",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=MaiWkTs8V+g=&fileName=Statement+of+Environmental+Effects+-+SEE.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/159033",
                       "title": "Site Plan and Elevations and Superseded Plan",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=2xpqra8gNb0=&fileName=Site+Plan+and+Elevations+and+Superseded+Plan.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/162569",
                       "title": "Assessment Report - Bldg Residential",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=bKYCMP01aJE=&fileName=Assessment+Report+-+Bldg+Residential.PDF"
                     },
                     {
                       "ref": "DOC18/168584",
                       "title": "Development Consent",
                       "document_url": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0/Document/Download?key=SxGG/yKi68s=&fileName=Development+Consent.PDF"
                     }
                   ],
                   "people": [
                     {
                       "name": "Alatalo Bros",
                       "role": "Applicant",
                       "contact": "02 6055 0180"
                     }
                   ],
                   "extended": {
                     "software_vendor": "Civica",
                     "software_vendor_url": "http://www.civica.com.au"
                   }
                 }
               }
             ],
             "count": 4,
             "pagination": {
               "previous": null,
               "next": 2,
               "current": 1,
               "per_page": 4,
               "count": 24091,
               "pages": 6023
             }
           }'

select * 
from OPENJSON(@json, '$.response')
with
    ([lot] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].land_title_ref.torrens.lot',
     [section] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].land_title_ref.torrens.section',
     [dpsp_id] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].land_title_ref.torrens.dpsp_id',
     [Street] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].address.street',
     [suburb] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].address.suburb',
     [state] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].address.state',
     [postcode] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].address.postcode',
     [geometry] varchar(200) '$.application.locations[0].geometry'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
      select L.*
      from OPENJSON(@json,'$.response') R
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(R.[value], '$.application.locations') 
       with
    (
    [lot] varchar(200) '$.land_title_ref.torrens.lot',
    [section] varchar(200) '$.land_title_ref.torrens.section',
    [dpsp_id] varchar(200) '$.land_title_ref.torrens.dpsp_id',
    [Street] varchar(200)  '$.address.street',
    [suburb] varchar(200) '$.address.suburb',
    [state] varchar(200) '$.address.state',
    [postcode] varchar(200) '$.address.postcode',
    [geometry] varchar(200) '$.geometry'
    ) L
```

[image]

The `locations` is an array, so we need to use cross apply and OPENSJON to get all elements.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, also means I don't have to type as much, and learnt something new here, happy days!

Comment: Actually I have a following up question, suppose I needed to include a second array? Like the last two lines here? I tried to put in another CROSS APPLY and aliasing it, but it did not like it, I also tried some different combinations after the $. but did not work either. I don't want to create another table just for those last two lines. How could I include 'reference'?

        (
 [related_apps] varchar(200) '$.related_apps',
 [more_info_url] varchar(200) '$.application.reference.more_info_url',
 [comments_url] varchar(200) '$.application.reference.comments_url'
        )L